# Xamarin.Android AOT: what's the risk?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

There's an AOT option in Xamarin.Android build, promising slightly better app startup time (highly needed...). Indeed, I enabled it, and the app starts faster. Yay \o/

However, this is marked as "experimental" and "not for production use".

What's the risk exactly?

- Does it sometimes break the build? (which sounds like an acceptable pain)
- Or does it unexpectedly go up in flames on certain devices? (which sounds like NO!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things:

- Your resulting APK becomes HUGE when using AOT.
- The feature is marked experimental, so as that indicates, the result may vary quality wise. Make sure to test every corner of your app on every ABI.

Your startup issues may be due to varying things. This could be, if you are doing a debug build, these are always slower than a release build on startup.
You may also be doing something bad during startup, like loading a whole bunch of assemblies that you only need later.
It could be so many things. However, switching to AOT will not fix *all* of those problems.

Comment: You're right about the "loading too many assemblies". It is actually the next thing to work on, performance wise. Any specific advise on that topic?

Comment: Lazy load everything.

Comment: Easier said than done :) A quick test shows that even if I do not instanciate / otherwise activate a class, the containing assembly is loaded before the app starts. I'm unsure how to delay that load.